# java Spring REST controller global security annotation

Tags: java, spring-security, annotations

I have been trying to secure Spring REST controllers and was able to achieve method level security using `@Secured({"myrole"})` annotation.

However, it seems to me that I have to annotate each method I want to secure.

Is there any other mechanism whereby all methods are secured by default and I can exclude them using some `Anonymous` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it's better to use expression based access control, so you will not have to add annotations everywhere. Here is the sample of xml-based context configuration.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
...
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('myrole')"/>
...
```

As far as I know there is no such annotation to override such default behavior, but you can do so by defining respective intercept-url pattern.
More on this you can check here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use security pointcuts like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.5.RELEASE/reference/ns-config.html) :

```
<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.mycompany.*Service.*(..))"
         access="ROLE_USER"/>
</global-method-security>
```

To know more about Pointcuts, read about [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

Here some [examples](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/03/writing-spring-aop-aspectj-pointcut-expressions-with-examples/) of how to work with Poincuts.